# importar texto .txt pra uma celula especifica do excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, txt

```
Sub importar_arquivo()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    importaArquivo End Sub

Private Function importaArquivo()
    Dim arquivo As String
    arquivo = abrirArquivo
    If arquivo <> Empty Then
        Debug.Print "ok"
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add 'nova planilha
        With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;" & arquivo & "", Destination:=Range("A1"))
            .Name = "teste"
            .FieldNames = True
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = True
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
            .SavePassword = False
            .SaveData = True
            .AdjustColumnWidth = True
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
            .TextFilePlatform = 850
            .TextFileStartRow = 1
            .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
            .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
            .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
            .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
            .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
            .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
            .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
            .TextFileOtherDelimiter = "|"
            .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
            .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        End With
    End If
    arquivo = "" End Function

Function abrirArquivo() As String
    Dim arquivo As String
    On Error GoTo sair:
    arquivo = ""
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
          'Selecção de apenas um aquivo
          .AllowMultiSelect = False
          'Filtro de extenção
          .Filters.Add "All files", "*.txt; *.csv"
          'Mostra a caixa de dialogo
          .Show
          'Armazena o caminho do arquivo
          arquivo = .SelectedItems.Item(1)
    End With
    abrirArquivo = arquivo sair:
    arquivo = "" End Function
```

Desculpem, é minha primeira vez aqui, e encontrei esse código que funcionou bem pra mim mas precisava de alguns ajustes, tentei fazer por conta própria mas sempre dá erro

- gostaria que esse código abrisse um arquivo .txt especifico (fica na mesma pasta do arquivo excel) e não uma janela pedindo pra solicitar o arquivo, nem abrir o arquivo .txt em paralelo.
- gostaria também que não abrisse numa nova planilha, mas numa célula  de uma planilha especifica, a ideia é ter uma pasta com imagens em .jpg e .txt com a descrição das imagens, e quando a pasta é atualizada as informações no excel tambem atualizem, a questão das imagens eu consegui resolver com imagens vinculadas, mas os textos eu preciso dos codigos VBA que eu não domino.

agradeço desde já

Comment: Você pode usar o `open`. Documentação: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/open-statement  Exemplo: https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/read-data-from-text-file.html

Answer (score -2):

Olá, fiz aqui uma nova versão do codigo.

```
Sub importar_arquivo()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    importaArquivo "C:\caminho\para\arquivo.txt", ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Nome da Planilha"), "B2"
End Sub

Private Function importaArquivo(caminhoArquivo As String, planilhaDestino As Worksheet, celulaDestino As String)
    If caminhoArquivo <> Empty Then
        Debug.Print "ok"
        With planilhaDestino.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "TEXT;" & caminhoArquivo & "",Destination:=planilhaDestino.Range(celulaDestino))
            .Name = "teste"
            .FieldNames = True
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = True
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
            .SavePassword = False
            .SaveData = True
            .AdjustColumnWidth = True
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
            .TextFilePlatform = 850
            .TextFileStartRow = 1
            .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
            .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
            .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
            .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
            .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
            .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
            .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
            .TextFileOtherDelimiter = "|"
            .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
            .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        End With
    End If
End Function
```

Só precisa de alterar o caminho do arquivo, o nome da planilha e célula de destino.